# Video won't play in HTML5 player

Tags: html5-video, firebase-storage

I'm trying to embed a video that is stored in firebase storage like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<video width="200" height="200"><source src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/msp-navigator-dev-3c0ae.appspot.com/o/vendor%2FJ6j3DGJugRDtHgOQqpWP%2F1591965492214-video.mp4?alt=media&token=03525328-fb90-4733-b109-84729707234f" type="video/mp4"></source></video>
</body>

</html>
```

However, the video won't show. I can download the video by following the URL just fine.

What is preventing this video from showing in the HTML5 player?

Comment: If I download this file and try to play it I get an error about a missing codec. Might be related.